# Reading binary data in c# / ReadAsync not reading everything specified in the count

Tags: c#, .net-core, filestream

I read this blogpost https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/readbinary.html,

> FileStream could be reading just the first 10 bytes of the file into the buffer. The Read method is only guaranteed to block until some data is available (or the end of the stream is reached)

Do you know if the same consideration needs to be done for ReadAsync.

Also do you know in which cases this condition will be hit, where Read / ReadAsync not reading everything specified in the count?

Answer (score 1):

> Also do you know in which cases this condition will be hit, where Read / ReadAsync not reading everything specified in the count?

When there is less data available then specified.

---

The most trivial one is where you hit end of file.

As [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.readasync?view=netcore-3.1) put it:

> The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached.

Also common; when reading from TCP/IP buffers, although usually that wouldn't be a `FileStream`. There are various other `Stream` inherited types, which share the same methods. See: [System.IO.Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1)

Comment: what I was wondering is if the program could hit this condition if it is reading a file locally, for example getting a batch of let's say 8192 bytes of a 150 mb file locally? Could a batch be partially read?

Comment: Yes, it does not have to be likely, but it is possible because it depends on your implementation of the FileStream and other components. A typical case could be faulty hardware or timeouts on read intructions.

Comment: @MariangeMarcano: so, in normal circumstances, if you read to the end, you'll get all the bytes.